# Re- work on Employee table - SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please find my

`Emp_Table`

```
Employee    Manager Employee Status
001            001  Active
002            001  Terminate
003            002  Active
004            002  Active
005            004  Terminate
006            005  Terminate
007            006  Active
008            006  Terminate
009            006  Active
```

I want to re-arrange the above table to represent each employee should have ACTIVE Manager.
i.e In my above table for the Employee 003 --> 002 (Manager is Terminated) Since I need to re-arrange this row to Active Manager
I need to see 002 is reporting to whom as per my above table 002 --> 001 Manager and Active too Since I need to update as 003 manager is 001

Please find my result table looks like - `Emp_Reworked_Table`

```
Employee    Manager Employee Status
001            001  Active
002            001  Terminate
003            001  Active
004            001  Active
005            004  Terminate
006            004  Terminate
007            004  Active
008            004  Terminate
009            004  Active
```

I have tried and find the solution but I dont know recursive query to perform for all employee.Please help

Comment: How do you know which active manager should replace a terminated one?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @MikeW, I need to look previous active manager list upto 001 = 001. Ex from Emp_Table:005 is the manager for 006 Since I need to check who is the manager for 005, in my case 004 is the manager for 005. Were as 004 is active since i need to update the manager for 006 as 004. Let me know if you need more clarification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may be over-killing my example below, but the gist of it is that you may want to use a [recursive CTE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

```
IF NOT EXISTS ( SELECT  1
                FROM    sys.objects
                WHERE   name = 'Emp_Table'
                    AND type = 'U' )
BEGIN
    --DROP TABLE dbo.Emp_Table;
    CREATE TABLE dbo.Emp_Table
    (
        EmpTable_PK         TINYINT IDENTITY( 1, 1 ) NOT NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY ( EmpTable_PK ),
        EmployeeCode        CHAR( 3 ),
        ManagerCode         CHAR( 3 ),
        EmployeeStatus      VARCHAR( 16 )
    );

    INSERT INTO dbo.Emp_Table ( EmployeeCode, ManagerCode, EmployeeStatus )
    SELECT  EmployeeCode, ManagerCode, EmployeeStatus
    FROM (      SELECT  EmployeeCode = NULL, ManagerCode = NULL, EmployeeStatus = NULL
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '001', '001', 'Active'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '002', '001', 'Terminate'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '003', '002', 'Active'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '004', '002', 'Active'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '005', '004', 'Terminate'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '006', '005', 'Terminate'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '007', '006', 'Active'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '008', '006', 'Terminate'
    UNION ALL   SELECT  '009', '006', 'Active' ) l
    WHERE   l.EmployeeCode IS NOT NULL
END;
GO

;WITH cte_Hierarchy AS (
    SELECT  et.EmpTable_PK, et.EmployeeCode, 
            et.ManagerCode, et.EmployeeStatus, 
            ManagerStatus = mt.EmployeeStatus
    FROM    dbo.Emp_Table et
    INNER JOIN dbo.Emp_Table mt
        ON  et.ManagerCode = mt.EmployeeCode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  h.EmpTable_PK, h.EmployeeCode,
            ManagerCode = et.ManagerCode, 
            h.EmployeeStatus,
            mt.EmployeeStatus
    FROM    cte_Hierarchy h
    INNER JOIN dbo.Emp_Table et
        ON  h.ManagerCode = et.EmployeeCode
    INNER JOIN dbo.Emp_Table mt
        ON  et.ManagerCode = mt.EmployeeCode
    WHERE   h.ManagerStatus = 'Terminate'
        AND et.EmployeeCode <> et.ManagerCode )
SELECT  EmployeeCode, ManagerCode, EmployeeStatus
FROM    cte_Hierarchy
WHERE   ManagerStatus = 'Active'
ORDER BY EmpTable_PK, EmployeeCode, ManagerCode;
```

Comment: @Avartx, Awesome Answer! I appreciate your response. Thanks.